# Menus not showing in the admin menu, after save

Tags: menus

I updated wordpress to v3.9, I added several custom links and pages in that menu, saved it and after that the menu editing UI disappeared:

Here is image how it looks now and what JS error it displays:

[image]
Things which i noticed:

- If I remove `post_type=nav_menu_item` from `wp_posts` and then the UI appear, of course without lunks, but right before the next save.

Comment: Questions should not depend upon third party resources. Please [edit] the question to include the image inline.

Comment: How it's now ? :)